# Is there a better way of handling templates in spring rather than Tiles?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Nowadays, website are generally divided into pieces of reusable template that are being rendered among different web pages. For example a site containing header, footer, menu etc. This items remains same through out the website and give it a common look and feel. It is very difficult to hard code this in each and every webpage and if later a change is needed than all the pages needs to be modified. Hence we use templatization mechanism. We create a common Header, Footer, Menu page and include this in each page.
We have found tiles in Spring which suffice our above need. But is there any better solution rather than tiles in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a rather direct swap for Tiles, then you could have a look at [Sitemesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh/Home). We've been using this rather successfuly for quite a bit of time now. The templating capabilities can be applied to Spring Web or JSF implementations (even if the later provides some other ways of doing so).

But I suspect you're more into finding a way out of simple templating, right ?